# Extracting columns from text file with different delimiters in Linux

Tags: linux

I have very large genotype files that are basically impossible to open in R, so I am trying to extract the rows and columns of interest using linux command line. Rows are straightforward enough using head/tail, but I'm having difficulty figuring out how to handle the columns.

If I attempt to extract (say) the 100-105th tab or space delimited column using

```
 cut -c100-105 myfile >outfile
```

this obviously won't work if there are strings of multiple characters in each column. Is there some way to modify cut with appropriate arguments so that it extracts the entire string within a column, where columns are defined as space or tab (or any other character) delimited?

Comment: Woah.  You mean `-c100-105`, not `-c100-1005`, don't you?  You don't want the one-thousand-and-fifth column?  The two answers submitted so far use 1005 !

Comment: Yes, I did, although the principle is still the same.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "obviously won't work if there are strings of multiple characters in each column".

Comment: Wierd that I found my answer in the question itself, the actual SO answer didn't work for me. Guess that would be due to my use case of extracting text from specific column range and paste it to text file

Answer (score 41, accepted):

If the command should work with both tabs and spaces as the delimiter I would use `awk`:

```
awk '{print $100,$101,$102,$103,$104,$105}' myfile > outfile
```

As long as you just need to specify 5 fields it is imo ok to just type them, for longer ranges you can use a `for` loop:

```
awk '{for(i=100;i<=105;i++)print $i}' myfile > outfile
```

---

If you want to use `cut`, you need to use the `-f` option:

```
cut -f100-105 myfile > outfile
```

If the field delimiter is different from `TAB` you need to specify it using `-d`:

```
cut -d' ' -f100-105 myfile > outfile
```

Check [the man page](http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/cut/) for more info on the cut command.

Comment: I believe this is not correct. You must have -d$'\t' for tab.

Comment: @amc It works for me, at least with GNU `cut`. I've added an awk command that can deal with both tabs and spaces.

Comment: Ah okay. I'm on a mac so that might be a difference.Thank you.

Answer (score 13):

You can use cut with a delimiter like this:

with space delim:

```
cut -d " " -f1-100,1000-1005 infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

with tab delim:

```
cut -d$'\t' -f1-100,1000-1005 infile.csv > outfile.csv
```

I gave you the version of cut in which you can extract a list of intervals...

Hope it helps!

Comment: +1 for mentioning that `-d$'\t'` syntax. (Although it isn't required because `TAB` is the default delimiter)

Comment: Alternatively you can use `awk --field-searator="\\t" '{print $1}' filename` syntax.

Comment: or simply `awk '{print $1}'` (tab is the default separator)