# Bash Shell (Text Prossing)

Tags: bash, shell

Given a tab delimited file with several columns (tsv format) print the first three fields.

Input Format

A tab-separated file with lines of ASCII text only.

Constraints

(N is the number of lines of text in the input file and C is the number of columns of data in the file)

Output Format

The output should contain N lines. For each line in the input, print the first three fields.

Sample Input

```
1   New York, New York[10]  8,244,910   1   New York-Northern New Jersey-Long Island, NY-NJ-PA MSA  19,015,900  1   New York-Newark-Bridgeport, NY-NJ-CT-PA CSA 22,214,083
2   Los Angeles, California 3,819,702   2   Los Angeles-Long Beach-Santa Ana, CA MSA    12,944,801  2   Los Angeles-Long Beach-Riverside, CA CSA    18,081,569
3   Chicago, Illinois   2,707,120   3   Chicago-Joliet-Naperville, IL-IN-WI MSA 9,504,753   3   Chicago-Naperville-Michigan City, IL-IN-WI CSA  9,729,825
4   Houston, Texas  2,145,146   4   Dallas-Fort Worth-Arlington, TX MSA 6,526,548   4   Washington-Baltimore-Northern Virginia, DC-MD-VA-WV CSA 8,718,083
5   Philadelphia, Pennsylvania[11]  1,536,471   5   Houston-Sugar Land-Baytown, TX MSA  6,086,538   5   Boston-Worcester-Manchester, MA-RI-NH CSA   7,601,061
```

my ans is -

```
cut -f-2
```

This is worng ans. Plz help me the correct ans...

Comment: duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19959746/extracting-columns-space-or-tab-delimited-from-text-file-in-linux

Answer (score 0):

Field numbering starts with 1, not 0.

```
cut -f-3
```

although it would be much clearer to type the two extra characters to write

```
cut -f 1-3
```